# Windows Application Forms: Leaving selected node expanded after clearing and re-populating the TreeView after new item is added C#

Tags: c#, treeview, windows

I have an application that allows users to add new items into a TreeView control. When an item is selected the parent node reveals its child nodes, but it collapses when a new item (Button is clicked) is added to the Treeview control. I want it to stay expanded until the user interacts with it again.

```
//List<> collection is initialized 
//Public class property is created to set it's member variables to the control values that the user enters 

private void addButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (ComboBoxOne.SelectedIndex != 0)
      { 
         //Method that adds new item to a List<> Collection
         AddToList(); 
         //Method that goes through the List<> Collection, modifies the display of the item and adds it to the TreeView control
         AddToTreeView();
      }
}

//How I am adding the List<> objects to the treeview control
private void TravelTreeView()
{
   TreeView1.Nodes.Clear();
   //Items is the class I created and ObjectList is the List<>
   foreach (Items obj in ObjectList)
   {
      TreeNode node = new TreeNode();

       node.Text = obj.Name;
       //Imagelist has 7 images
       node.SelectedImageIndex = 0;
       node.ImageIndex = obj.NameImage;
       node.Nodes.Add(obj.AgeImage, "Age: " + obj.Age, 5);
       node.Nodes.Add(obj.ZodiacImage, "Zodiac: " + obj.Zodiac, 6);
       node.Nodes.Add(obj.JobImage, "Job: " + obj.Job, 7);

       TreeView1.Nodes.Add(node);
   }

}
```

Comment: Have you made sure that you call the `Expand()` method on the `TreeNode` which you are adding ? You can also make use of the `IsExpanded` property of the TreeNode to check if it is Expanded or Collapsed and then perform the action accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I see that TreeView is cleared and then populated with list of nodes. As mentioned in the comment(s) you may check for IsExpanded property and then decide to call Expand on TreeNode.

Another way: As you are adding many new TreeNodes I would assume there is no previous state for these nodes to check for IsExpanded, in such a case, you may try something like below, the new Node is added in expanded state. Note Beginupdate/EndUpdate calls.

```
    private void TravelTreeView()
    {
        // better to do this to avoid too many repaints
        TreeView1.BeginUpdate();

        TreeView1.Nodes.Clear();
        //Items is the class I created and ObjectList is the List<>
        foreach (Items obj in ObjectList)
        {
           TreeNode node = new TreeNode();

           node.Text = obj.Name;
           //Imagelist has 7 images
           node.SelectedImageIndex = 0;
           node.ImageIndex = obj.NameImage;
           node.Nodes.Add(obj.AgeImage, "Age: " + obj.Age, 5);
           node.Nodes.Add(obj.ZodiacImage, "Zodiac: " + obj.Zodiac, 6);
           node.Nodes.Add(obj.JobImage, "Job: " + obj.Job, 7);

           // add an expanded Node
           node.Expand();

           TreeView1.Nodes.Add(node);
       }
       // we are done with the updates to TreeView
       TreeView1.EndUpdate();
    }
```

Comment: The item should be collapsed until the user interacts with it, your code expands it when it's added to the TreeView and I don't want it to do that.

Comment: @BeginnerCoder I see. However, your original questions "_...but it collapses when a new item (Button is clicked) is added to the Treeview control. I want it to stay expanded until the user interacts with it again._" says otherwise... Staying collapsed should be achieved by not doing anything special. Obviously, when user interacts, it will expand when user expands. Perhaps, I am not able to understand your problem.

Comment: I don't think you understood the problem, so I'm going to rephrase myself and apologize for the inconvenience. When the new items are added to the TreeView, they appear collapsed (this is what I want it to do), but let's say the user decided to open the first node and then decides to add a new node to the TreeView. Whenever a new item is added to the TreeView, it closes whatever nodes are expanded. I don't want it to do that. I hope that makes better sense.

Comment: @BeginnerCoder WinForms is a _Statefull_ application so the nodes which were expanded or collapsed would remain irrespective of adding or removing nodes. However, the problem could be because you seem to be clearing and adding all the nodes back(`TreeView1.Nodes.Clear();`), in which case the `TreeView` is brought to an initial state. You could avoid clearing it and instead check `TreeView1.Contains(TreeNode node)` to see if the node you want to add already exists and then proceed with adding newer nodes.

Comment: So research Treeview.Contains()?

Comment: @BeginnerCoder Yes. Also, there are several ways to do this. In essence you are after all going to only make sure that instead of clearing and re adding, you just check if items exists and if not only then add it. A simple `TreeView1.Nodes.ContainsKey(obj.Name);` would suffice since you are using the Name property and the Name property corresponds to the Key in case of `TreeView`

Answer (score 0):

WinForms does retain the state of the controls. The issue here seems to be the fact that you clean the items and then iterate your object and then reload the TreeView. In this case the items would be collapsed which is the default.

I would suggest the below approach,

```
private void TravelTreeView()
    {
        //Items is the class I created and ObjectList is the List<>
        foreach (Items obj in ObjectList)
        {
            //Check to see if the item already exists
            if (!TreeView1.Nodes.ContainsKey(obj.Name))
            {
                var node = new TreeNode();
                node.Text = obj.Name;
                //Imagelist has 7 images
                node.SelectedImageIndex = 0;
                node.ImageIndex = obj.NameImage;
                node.Nodes.Add(obj.AgeImage, "Age: " + obj.Age, 5);
                node.Nodes.Add(obj.ZodiacImage, "Zodiac: " + obj.Zodiac, 6);
                node.Nodes.Add(obj.JobImage, "Job: " + obj.Job, 7);

                TreeView1.Nodes.Add(node);
            }
        }
    }
```

Information on the [ContainsKey](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treenodecollection.containskey(v=vs.110).aspx) Method on TreeNodeCollection

Comment: The expanded node stays open when a new item is entered, but there are duplicates now. How can I get rid of them?

Comment: I should also add in that I'm going to be keeping count of how many nodes are added to the treeview and will be adding the ages together each time a new node is added. For example: if the first node age is 9, it will display 9 in the textbox and if a second node is added with an age that is 10, the textbox should display 19.

Comment: @BeginnerCoder Duplicates in the TreeView nodes ? Please check the data that you are passing in. You need to have a unique property in your object that you can work off of, or handle grouped items in a way which you want. Handling duplicates however is an entirely different issue.